# How to customize a Destroy() Action in the Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: popup, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, destroy

Can someone tell me how to customize the css, the message and the text in the "Yes" / "No" buttons in the popup launched by the Destroy() method in the Kendo UI Grid?

My code looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ActivityModel>(Model.Activities)
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns( columns => {
    columns.Bound( c => c.Name ).Width(50);
    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(90);
})
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can only customize the text of confirmation of deletion of row. If you want to customize the message then better option is to use custom command button that deletes the row and you can setup the pop up design as per your requirement. Please refer below link for custom command in kendo grid.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command